# как работает SSL handshake

Tags: ssl

можете подсказать вот что:

сервер отправляет клиенту свой сертификат и открытый ключ во время SSL handshake.
 Как клиент может быть уверен что этот открытый ключ принадлежит именно серверу отправившему его плюс сертификат?

правильно ли я понимаю, открытый ключ сервера был вместе с сертификатом подписан CA ?  Если да, то как безопасно предоставить для подписи открытый ключ удостоверяющему центру?

Comment: Кратко: сертификат подписан центром сертификации, которому клиент доверяет по умолчанию

Comment: @andreymal  мне остаётся непонятным как безопасно отослать центру сертификации открытый ключ и сертификат? вдруг злоумышленник изменит открытый ключ во время его передачи центру

Comment: Упомянутая проблема действительно существует в некоторых случаях, но вообще по умолчанию ничего никому отсылать не нужно, подпись проверяется умной математикой в оффлайне. [Вот эта статья в википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) вроде бы про это, здесь в ответе может кто-нибудь простыми словами ещё расскажет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> сервер отправляет клиенту свой сертификат и открытый ключ

Открытый ключ является частью сертификата.

> мне остаётся непонятным как безопасно отослать центру сертификации
>   открытый ключ и сертификат? вдруг злоумышленник изменит открытый ключ
>   во время его передачи центру

Используя SSL-соединение (HTTPS, почта поверх SSL, FTPS и т.д.). Оно защищает от атаки MITM (человек по средине).

Центр сертификации пришлет вам обратно подписанный сертификат. Если вдруг окажется, что подписали неверный сертификат, вы можете запросить отмену, и центр сертификации добавит его в revocation list (такой список сертификатов, где подпись и срок годности правильные, но по каким-то причинам этому сертификату не стоит доверять).

Comment: у сервера есть открытый ключ центра сертификации, так что он может им зашифровать свой сертификат с ключем и отварить ему на подпись. Центр расшифрует сертификат своим закрытым кличем, правильно я понял?

Comment: @voipp Нет, здесь не используется асимметричное шифрование. Центр сертификации не использует ваш публичный ключ. Он подписывает ваш сертификат при помощи приватного ключа (от своего сертификата, который будет лежать выше в цепочке перед вашим), и добавляет эту подпись в ваш сертификат.

Comment: ну смотрите, что бы подписать сертификат, этот центр сертификации должен его получить (вместе с открытым ключем клиента). А как безопасно его получить

Comment: Что бы центр его безопасно получил - я написал в ответе, для этого вы должны переслать его по защищенному соединению. Что бы вы его безопасно получили от центра, тут уже нет разницы, там стоит подпись, которую невозможно подделать.